# remove element from list

Tags: prolog

```
del(X,[X|Reszta],Reszta).
del(X,[Y|Ogon],[Y|Reszta]) :- del(X,Ogon,Reszta).
```

I don't understand this code. If I ask:

```
?- del(c, [a,b,c],X).
```

Compiler will go to the second line, and he will trigger a recursion loop `del(x,[b,c],[])`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how the interpreter works by typing (well, in swi-pl at least, should be something similar in other implementations) :

```
?- trace, del(c, [a,b,c],X).
```

BTW, you certainly forgot to include a line such as :

```
del(_, [], []).
```

Else the algorithm doesn't initialize the result list.
Then it's really basic : if the first element of the list is unifiable with the one you want to remove, you skip it, else, you include it in the result list.

So basicly here, it will work like that :
del(c, [a, b, c], X) => c can't be unified with a so we will include a when constructing the list from the end.
del(c, [b, c], X) => c can't be unified with b so we will include b when constructing the list from the end.
del(c, [c], X) => c can be unified with c so we won't include c when constructing the list from the end.
del(c, [], X) => [] is true when X = [] so let's say X = [] and now let's construct our result list by climbing up the recursion :
X = [] when climbing up one step because c isn't included.
X = [b] when climbing up one step because b is included.
X = [a, b] when climbing up one step because a is included.

Answer (score 1):

use trace/0 to see what will happen. in this case:

```
    4 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 4 ?- del(c,[a,b,c],X).
   Call: (6) del(c, [a, b, c], _G531) ? creep
   Call: (7) del(c, [b, c], _G607) ? creep
   Call: (8) del(c, [c], _G610) ? creep
   Exit: (8) del(c, [c], []) ? creep
   Exit: (7) del(c, [b, c], [b]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) del(c, [a, b, c], [a, b]) ? creep
X = [a, b] .
```

at each "turn" prolog will check if the first element is the one we want to remove.
if it is, we are done.
otherwise, we keep the head and recursively call del/3 for the tail of the list

whether or not we should think about what happens if the element is not in the given list is another matter; we might want the predicate to fail in that case, we might want to return the whole list and then we should add the `del(_, [], []).` as mog said